# why does pandas drop all of the rows of the dataFrame in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to drop rows with missing values (NaN) from a 1400 row dataframe with the following code:

```
df.dropna(axis=0)
```

and although the dataFrame had 600 missing values total, the resulting dataframe had no rows at all!

To my knowledge, dropna() drops rows with at least one missing value. How is it possible that with 600 total missing values all of the rows are dropped?

Comment: What is `df.isnull().sum().sum()`? (Probably a lot more than 600)

Comment: You are right!!! 6k. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your case, it will drop all rows with missing values. Use IsNa() to verify the row values and check.